# C# Windows Form KeyCombination Detect Failed without anything feedback

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I need to detect if user hit `Ctrl + Enter` on my classic C# windows form (the key combination will call to `Submit()` method), but when I come with this code, it failed without any feedback, how can I fix it?

```
private void OneNumberEntry_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work without any feedback, I tried `breakpoint` but the cursor never run to that line of code. 
here is my form: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/GeovXcH.png), the key combination often got trigger when the textbox is focusing.

Comment: What control do you want the event to be attached to? What is `OneNumberEntry`?

Comment: I've tried and the event works when attached to the textbox, but could I make it work anytime regardless how many control I have (textbox, masked textbox, text area, grid..)?